# Reverse pixelated pics

Tags: pixelation

With pixelated characters all the rage and other annoying nfts.
I'm wanting to find out if I can take an image and reverse the pixelation. We found some GitHub repos with some depixelating algorithm implementations. Trying to get them to actually work is a challenge though. It's an implentation of an algorithm that a guy named Johannes Kopf invented a while back. So some of the code is like 2 years old and outdated

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! What exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you have an example showing what kind of image you are talking about?  "pixelated characters" is very ambiguous.  Do you mean human figures, letters? Are you asking about vectorizing a design? What do you mean by "annoying nfts"?  Not sure if this has anything to do with graphic design to be honest. You mention coding and algorithms, but these are generally off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no true way to de-pixelize an image because that information is simply not a part of the image. You can train neural networks to *guess* at what the original image is (it makes these guesses by using data from a bunch of other original vs pixelated images) but that's a complete guess/calculation, not the true original image.

Comment: You might note that this is not truly any dofferent than scaling up the image and theres lots of stuff for scaling up pictures with AI tech that one can use now.

Comment: To make your answer complete you could mention the most common upscaling interpolation methods available in graphical applications. Including the AI assisted methods in Photoshop.

Comment: @Wolff I never use Photoshop or any graphical application regularly, so I don't know much about those :)

Comment: Fair enough, but "de-pixelizing" is basically the same as upscaling using some interpolation so I just thought it would help the OP to think about it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I found this 100 x 100 pixels image you have published recently:

[image]

It's really pixelated when watched in big size. It also has heavy noise; I guess a big part of it is caused by the image compression.

There exists image resizing software which try to guess sharp edges and thin lines. Often it succeeds remarkably well. This is the result when one such program (=On1 Resize) is applied to your image:

[image]

The image has now 600 x 600 pixels and some sharp edges seem to be guessed right. Interpolations cannot do the same, they would treat all parts of the image in the same way (= the pixelated borders would be changed to blurry ones, but no sharp non-pixelated edges would be generated)

Some areas seem to have got fake details when the noise is scaled and sharpened, too. The  result would be better if the image wasn't as noisy.

NOTE: No real information has become visible, because it doesn't exist, all details are only guesses.

If you want to try this get a demo of some image resizing program. On1 Resize has hanged around about a quarter of century with different trade names. It's not based on AI which could recognize common items in images and make better guesses based on its knowledge. I do not have such advanced software.

There's also freeware. Smilla Enlargener is very simple to use and it scales RGB images approximately as well as On1 Resize.